# How do you make the Qt source code available when debugging an application in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt

I recently decided to compile Qt from source. I was under the mistaken understanding that doing so would mean that I would now be able to see the Qt source code when debugging my applications. However, when my stack involves Qt code, the stack is still shown in grey in the right panel and only bytecode is shown for the execution.

[image]

Is there a specific option I need to pass to the `configure` script to enable this? Is this even possible?

Comment: I too have been wondering about that  It seems like a pain in the behind, but I'm sure that placing the cpp files into the include paths should help - either that or place them into the include folders so the IDE can pick it up.

Comment: Generally, if you have the DLL (and you compiled with debug) a .pdb file with the same name as the outputted DLL file should be put where the app .exe file is (depending on config). If you have the source files, I'm sure they can be added to some config option that looks for debugging source files. I use MSVS 2010, so I'm not as helpful with the app you have here.

Comment: @OyvindAndersson - I'm actually developing in Linux, so I don't have DLLs, but this may apply similarly to `.so` files...

Comment: Are you building with symbols (debug) or release (no symbols)?  You may want to change the build instructions or parameters.

Comment: One of the parameters that I gave `configure` was `-debug-and-release`, which from what I understand should give me both debug and release symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar problem when using Emacs+gdb. The problem was that
path to source code compiled in library was something like src/core/qobject.cpp
or even core/qobject.cpp. So debuger can not find suitable source file when
I walk up and down through call stack. I solve the problem just configure
gdb's search path. In qt creator you can try fix it by finding option to configure "gdb" parameters and add "-d path/to/qt/source/code" to gdb command line arguments.